# Add more info about event in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

How can I add more information to a specific view?

I want to display more info about my events with the dayAgenda view from my mysql table (the values that are already stored into the array coming from my json-events.php).

I read the documentation of the fullcalendar, especially about eventRender, but I do not understand the explanation of the code.

Please, how can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Know that anywhere you can call an "event object" you can call any of the fields you desire from your array. AKA.

```
eventRender: function(event){
    var description = event.description; 
    var firstname = event.firstname;} //or
eventMouseover: function(event){
    var description = event.description; 
    var lastname = event.lastname;} // or
eventResize(event): function(event){
    var description = event.description; 
    var place = event.place;} // you get the picture...
```

Also you can specify a specific view by using...

```
var view = calendar.fullCalendar('getView');
if(view.name === "agendaDay"){
    // do something
}
```

or by using some of the built in view objects inside the callbacks like...

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view){
    if(view.name === "agendaDay"){
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can provide your own rendering logic using the `eventRender` callback:

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    if (view.name === "agendaDay") {
        element.find(".fc-event-content")
            .append("<b>Description</b>:" + event.description);
    }
}
```

Where `description` is one of your custom event properties. You may have to change your rendering logic depending on the view the person is currently on.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/LjCV9/ (click the **Day** button on the top right of the calendar)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to add informational flags to my events.  Nicely done!

Comment: @andrew can you check my thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60741694/how-to-show-date-and-weekday-name-in-fullcallendar

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
eventRender: function (objEvent, element, view) {
    if (view.name === "agendaDay") { //or agendaWeek
        element.find(".fc-content")
                .append("<b>Other Info</b>:<br/>" + objEvent.otherInfo);
    }
} });
```